# How to hide command prompt window while running .bat file using nsIProcess?

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, cmd, xul

**My code:**

```
var fpath="C:\\TVT_"+cur_date+"_"+cur_time+".avi";

Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var env = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
var shell = new FileUtils.File(env.get("COMSPEC"));

var args = ["/c", "cd.. & cd.. & C: & cd C:/ffmpeg/bin & record.bat "+fpath];

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(shell);
process.runAsync(args, args.length);
```

When I execute the batch file through this code then always a command prompt window prompt displays.

Is there any way to hide that window and run batch process silently ?

***Using Windows XP and Firefox 12.0***

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that Firefox can run a batch file without a console window. However, this is possible using Windows Scripting Host via [`WshShell.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (`intWindowStyle` parameter must be 0). You would need a JScript file, e.g. `record.js` with the contents:

```js
var dir = WScript.ScriptFullName.replace(/[\/\\]+[^\/\\]*$/, "");
var Shell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");
Shell.CurrentDirectory = dir;
Shell.Run("record.bat", 0, true);
```

This script deduces the directory from its own path and runs `record.bat` in the same directory. You could then run this script like this:

```js
var script = new FileUtils.File("c:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\record.js");

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(script);
process.runAsync([], 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Wladimir, but when I run this code with record.js then it shows an "open with" dialogue box, and after clicking on open button, it shows record.js file's code..and code does not execute. If I replace path with "c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe" then it is working good and open a notepad window.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe `.js` files aren't associated with WSH by default on Windows XP or you changed the file association? Then you would have to run `WScript.exe` with the script path as parameter explicitly (to locate it use the `SystemRoot` environment variable and append `system32\WScript.exe` then).

Answer (score 0):

To run batch process silently add `@echo off` at the first line of it.

Comment: It's impossible to hide window at all, it's possible only to hide output.

Comment: @echo off won't even hide the output.